# Asymptotic behaviour of a sum of powers of consecutive integers

Tags: analysis

I am searching for the asymptotic behavior of the sum

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk^n$ when $n$ tends to infinity

As someone an idea?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: As a very crude approximation,
$$
\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}+1} = \frac{n}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n k^n \leq n\cdot n^{n} = n^{n+1}
$$

Comment: Is it $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk^n$ or $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk^p$ ?

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^p$ can be estimated by an integral to give $\sim \frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}$. Not sure about $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^n$.

Comment: @Laertes: I don't see why your estimate wouldn't hold for the specific case $p=n$. Both are fixed, so it shouldn't matter if it happens that they coincide, right?

Comment: @MPW Because $n$ is $not$ fixed; the OP is asking about the behavior of the expression as $n$ tends to infinity. It turns out that it does hold--see Olivier's answer--but you need to go through the steps to see that; since we're integrating with respect to one variable but not another, we can't assume that we can substitute one for the other afterwards.